# redirect url for accounts-github in codebox

Tags: authentication, redirect, meteor, meteorite

I'm a windows user and I'm working on meteor application in codebox.io

In this I want github authentication and I've created application in github and gave redirect url as

```
http://web-3000.0bxxxx367-d592-4xx6-9xx7-7d10fxxa8c1.vm1.dynobox.io/
```

That is where my application is running and i gave the redirect url the sam

But when I tried to click on the login button it is not even displaying the github login page, It is displaying my application homepage,

What to give in the url, help me with this